# using different signature for different content in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, http-headers, beanshell

I'm trying to do performance testing using JMeter to test my api http post.
I need signature in my header before I request to http post. So I use HTTP Header Manager. However, the signature depends on content of the body. How can I generate different signature for different content of the body. At the same time, I need to set thread to 10 as I want to send multiple request at the same time.

The signature must be correct for its body. I've been using beanshell to generate signature. However, I still can't resolve the issue. any pointer would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. The problem might be connected with Beanshell itself, my expectation is that generating signature is a resource intensive operation and Beanshell performance can be a big question mark. Since JMeter 3.1 it is [recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for any form of scripting the reasons are in:

   - Groovy supports modern Java features while Beanshell has [Java 1.5 syntax](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/grid/java-5-features-083037.html)
   - Groovy has its own [syntax sugar](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/) on top of Java SDK
   - [Groovy performance is much better](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) comparing to other scripting options available in JMeter
2. Location of the HTTP Header Manager also can matter, I would recommend organising your Test Plan as follows:

   - HTTP Request Sampler - to do the actual work

     - [JSR223 PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) - to generate the signature
     - HTTP Header Manager - to hold the signature
     - [Synchronizing Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer) - to ensure that all 10 threads will be executed at exactly the same moment.